# How to insert an integer into a sorted list

Tags: haskell

I tried to insert an integer at the correct position into a sorted list of integers.

```
insert :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
insert x [] = [x] 
insert x [y:ys] = if x <= y
                  then [x:y:ys]
                  else y insert x [ys]
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here and how to fix it? Here are the errors I have encountered:

[image: Error output]

Comment: In future questions, please don't use images for code or error messages. Paste them as text instead.

Answer (score 5):

You have several errors here.

- In the argument list, `y:ys` is already a list, there is no need in wrapping it again like `[y:ys]`, - this has type `[[Int]]`, that is, a list of lists. Note that we still have to put brackets here, to tell Haskell that this is a single function agument: `(y:ys)`.
- In your "then" clause, again, `x:y:ys` is already a list, - don't wrap it into `[x:y:ys]`.
- In your "else" clause, `y insert x [ys]` is *function application* - Haskell thinks that `y` is a function that you are applying to arguments `insert`, `x` and `[ys]`. You need operator `:` here, like `y : insert ...`
- Again, in your "else" clause, you repeat the first error: `ys` is already a list, don't wrap it into `[ys]`.

So, a fixed solution would be:

```
insert :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
insert x [] = [x] 
insert x (y:ys) = if x <= y
                  then x:y:ys
                  else y : insert x ys
```

Answer (score 3):

You are treating `y` as a function, not an element. You need to use `:` to construct a new list. Also, for a list, you use `[...]` *or* `x:xs`, not both. `[x,y]` is syntactic sugar for `x:y:[]`.

```
insert x [] = x
insert x (y:ys) = if x <= y
                  then x:y:ys
                  else y : insert x ys
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, probably not most efficient but still should be good (w/o explicit recursion and pattern matching on list):

```
insert :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
insert x l = let (lower, greater) = span (< x) l in lower ++ x : greater
```

And this solution is also lazy as you can see:

```
λ: insert 3 [1,2,4]
[1,2,3,4]
λ: take 10 $ insert 5 $ repeat 1
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```